# Unknown attributes account id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a devise model named "account", and i'm trying to create friendships between users using a friendship model that has a initiator user id and a friend user id.
I have a view with a list of users that the current user can add, and when he press the add button, the friendship should be created:

```
 <td><%= link_to "Add Friend", friendships_path(:friend_id => account.id), :method => :post %></td>
```

I'm having the following error:
unknown attribute: account_id

```
 def create
    @friendship = current_account.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
    if @friendship.save
      flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "Account"
end
```

Comment: can’t really say much from this, the problem is likely in the `Friendship` model, could you post more information about the `Friendship` model? and preferably a full stack trace

Comment: unfortunately I still can’t say much from this, it is likely related to how you modelled the data. Does `Friendship` have both `account_id` and `friend_id` in the schema? You might also need to explicitly specify the `foreign_key` for the second `belongs_to` statement.

Comment: friendship have user_id and friend_id in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

If, like you said, the `Friendship` schema has user_id and friend_id, this error:

```
unknown attribute: account_id
```

is normal. Just rename user_id to account_id in the schema and it should works.